# Why does the web page title change to "(1) Ask Ubuntu", "(2) Ask Ubuntu", etc?

Tags: support

Occasionally the page title changes to "(1) Ask Ubuntu", "(2) Ask Ubuntu", etc - I think I have seen it up to (4). What is the number in the brackets telling me? Is this related to the number of open tabs?

Here is a screenshot: [image: Screenshot]

Comment: It is because of unread messages (posts).

Comment: OK, makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, it is the number of questions with new activity:

[image]

Click on that small bar and the new questions will load and the number will get reset.

Comment: Dang, well I had a shorter tab when I added that comment. (Only Showed Ask Ubuntu, not full Ask Ubuntu General) I should have looked more carefully